# Java approach to get value from multiple maps

Tags: multithreading, java-8

I have 3 maps and I need to get a certain value(ip-address) from any of the 3 maps by searching them parallelly and once found in any map the search should stop for the other 2 maps. Please suggest how could this be done in Java8+. I took the 2 below approaches but it did not succeed. Please suggest.

**Approach 1 : Observable (RxJava3)**

```
 Observable.concatArrayEagerDelayError(getIpFromMap1(map1), getIpFromMap2(map2))
                .subscribe(ipAddressVal -> ipAddress.set(ipAddressVal));
        System.out.println(ipAddress.get());

 private Observable<String> getIpFromMap1(Map<String, String> map1) {
        return Observable.fromIterable(map1.entrySet())
                .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().equals("ip-address"))
                .firstElement()
                .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
                .flatMapObservable(Observable::just);
    }

    private Observable<String> getIpFromMap2(Map<String, String> map2) {
        return Observable.fromIterable(map2.entrySet())
                .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().equals("ip-address"))
                .firstElement()
                .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
                .flatMapObservable(Observable::just);
    }
```

The problem with this approach is RxJava being single-threaded by default will run the operators in a single thread.

**Approach 2 : MultiThreading**

```
@AllArgsConstructor
class MyThread3 extends Thread{

    private String name;



    @Override
    public void run() {

        Map<String,String> map1 = new HashMap<>();
        map1.put("net-ip","333");map1.put("ip-address","132333");
        Map<String,String> map2 = new HashMap<>();
        map2.put("hostname","kekdkd");map2.put("ip-address","232233");map2.put("operating-system","win11");
        Map<String,String> map3 = new HashMap<>();
        map3.put("processor","intel");map3.put("ip-address","344322");map3.put("graphics","nvidia");
        AtomicReference<String> ipAddress = new AtomicReference<>();
        if(name.equals("t1") && StringUtils.isEmpty(ipAddress.get())){
            map1.entrySet().stream().filter(entry -> entry.getKey().equals("ip-address")).findFirst().ifPresent(entry -> ipAddress.set(entry.getValue()));
        }else if(name.equals("t2") && StringUtils.isEmpty(ipAddress.get())){
            map2.entrySet().stream().filter(entry -> entry.getKey().equals("ip-address")).findFirst().ifPresent(entry -> ipAddress.set(entry.getValue()));
        }else if(name.equals("t3") && StringUtils.isEmpty(ipAddress.get())){
            map3.entrySet().stream().filter(entry -> entry.getKey().equals("ip-address")).findFirst().ifPresent(entry -> ipAddress.set(entry.getValue()));
        }

        System.out.println("ipAddress :: " + ipAddress);

    }
}
public class ThreadsSimultaneousEx {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MyThread3 t1 = new MyThread3("t1");
        MyThread3 t2 = new MyThread3("t2");
        MyThread3 t3 = new MyThread3("t3");

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();

    }
}
```

This is giving the ip-address value from all 3 maps. I need from any 1 map and soon as it is found in 1 the other 2 threads should stop. Please suggest.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need multi-threading, just make use of the `Map` property that you can directly get the value assigned to a key if you know the key. So you don't have to iterate through all entries, which would end up with an execution time of O(n) (execution time increases by the number of entries in the maps).

```
String ipAddress;
ipAddress = map1.get("ip-address");
if (ipAddress == null) {
    ipAddress = map2.get("ip-address");
    if (ipAddress == null) {
        ipAddress = map3.get("ip-address");
    }
}
System.out.println("ipAddress :: " + ipAddress);
```

If you use `HashMap` for `map1` `map2` and `map3` this implementation has a run-time of O(1) (constant execution time, independent of the number of entries in all the maps). This implementation is faster than any parallelization you could implement.

Answer (score 2):

You could also retrieve it using nested [getOrDefault](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault(java.lang.Object,V)) invocations.  In this implementation, if it doesn't appear in any map it will return an informative string.

```
Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<>(Map.of());
Map<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<>(Map.of());
Map<String, String> map3 = new HashMap<>(Map.of("ip-address", "10.0.0.1"));
 
String key = "ip-address";
String s = map1.getOrDefault(key, 
              map2.getOrDefault(key,
                 map3.getOrDefault(key, "No Value Found"))); 
                         
System.out.println(s);
```

prints

```
10.0.0.1
```

If you're certain it will be in one of the maps, replace the last `getOrDefault()` with just `get()`.